# How can I detect CSS Variable support with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css, browser-feature-detection, css-variables

The latest version of Firefox has support for [CSS Variables](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-variables/), but Chrome, IE and loads of other browsers do not. It should be possible to access a DOM Node or write a little method which returns whether the browser supports this feature, but I haven't been able to find anything which is currently able to do this. What I need is a solution which I can use as condition to run code if the browser does not support the feature, something like:

```
if (!browserCanUseCssVariables()) {
  // Do stuff...
}
```

Comment: I can't find any feature detection for this functionality. Personally, I'd recommend not bothering with it, yet. There are no plans to implement this in chrome yet, not to mention IE...

Comment: Here is a list of supported browsers: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-variables

Comment: Exactly, but im working on a javascript version which should replace that behaivior - which of course should only do its magic if the browser cant. https://github.com/IceReaper/NextCSS

Comment: Note that Firefox does not support accessing CSS variables via CSSOM, even though it currently supports declaring and using them in CSS. If you're only feature-detecting the CSS side of things without trying to access the values themselves, though, then it shouldn't be too much of a problem.

Comment: This no longer the case, check [this](https://caniuse.com/css-variables). IE is the only major browser that doesn't support CSS variables.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

We can do this with [`CSS.supports`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS.supports). This is the JavaScript implementation of CSS's `@supports` rule which is currently available in Firefox, Chrome, Opera and Android Browser (see [Can I Use...](http://caniuse.com/#search=css.supports)).

> The `CSS.supports()` static methods returns a Boolean value indicating if the browser supports a given CSS feature, or not.
> – [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS.supports)

With this, we can simply:

```
CSS.supports('color', 'var(--fake-var)');
```

The result of this will be `true` if the browser supports CSS variables, and `false` if it doesn't.

(You might think that `CSS.supports('--fake-var', 0)` would work, but as noted in comments on this answer Safari seems to have a bug there making it fail.)

### Pure JavaScript Example

On Firefox this code snippet will produce a green background, as our `CSS.supports` call above returns `true`. In browsers which do not support CSS variables the background will be red.

```js
var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];

if (window.CSS && CSS.supports('color', 'var(--fake-var)')) {
  body.style.background = 'green';
} else {
  body.style.background = 'red';
}
```

Note that here I've also added checks to see whether `window.CSS` exists - this will prevent errors being thrown in browsers which do not support this JavaScript implementation and treat that as `false` as well. (`CSS.supports` was introduced at the same time `CSS` global was introduced, so there's no need to check for it as well.)

### Creating the `browserCanUseCssVariables()` function

In your case, we can create the `browserCanUseCssVariables()` function by simply performing the same logic. This below snippet will alert either `true` or `false` depending on the support.

```js
function browserCanUseCssVariables() {
  return window.CSS && CSS.supports('color', 'var(--fake-var)');
}

if (browserCanUseCssVariables()) {
    alert('Your browser supports CSS Variables!');
} else {
    alert('Your browser does not support CSS Variables and/or CSS.supports. :-(');
}
```

### The Results (all tested on Windows only)

#### Firefox v31

[image: Firefox]

#### Chrome v38

[image: Chrome]

#### Internet Explorer 11

[image: IE11]

Comment: Doesn't work with Chrome while CSS experimental features enabled. No matter what it always returns false

Comment: Work in Chrome Version 60 stable - typed into console: "window.CSS && window.CSS.supports && window.CSS.supports('--fake-var', 0)",  returns true

Comment: @ChrisMorgan When I try `window.CSS.supports('--fake-var', 0)` on Safari 12.0.2 it returns `false` but CSS variables are in fact supported. This returns true however (taken from Modernizr): `window.CSS.supports('color', 'var(--primary)')`

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, good to know. So the two that *should* be equivalent are in fact not in Safari (presumably a bug), and so checking a `var(--x)` *value* should be preferred to a `--x` *property*. I’ve updated the answer to work around that bug.

Comment: The Mozilla documentation uses `CSS.supports('(--foo: red)')` which seems more straightforward. Nicely written answer though.

Answer (score 8):

Set a CSS style with CSS variables and proof with Javascript and `getComputedStyle()` if it is set...
`getComputedStyle()` is supported in many browsers: http://caniuse.com/#feat=getcomputedstyle

**HTML**

```
<div class="css-variable-test"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
:root {
  --main-bg-color: rgb(1, 2, 3); /* or something else */
}

.css-variable-test {
    display: none;
    background-color: var(--main-bg-color);
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
var computedStyle = getComputedStyle(document.getElementsByClassName('css-variable-test')[0], null);

if (computedStyle.backgroundColor == "rgb(1, 2, 3)") { // or something else
    alert('CSS variables support');
}
```

FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/g0naedLh/6/

Comment: If you have access to modifying the CSS then this solution is probably better than mine, purely because not all browsers currently support JavaScript's implementation of `CSS.supports` which my answer relies upon. So +1 to this!

Comment: @JamesDonnelly Thx, actually your solution is absolutely correct, because only firefox supports this and also supports `CSS.supports`... Nice solution.

Answer (score 8):

You don’t need Javascript to detect if a browser supports custom properties, unless the `Do stuff...` is Javascript itself. Since the thing you’re detecting support for is CSS, *I assume that the stuff you’re trying to do is all CSS*. Therefore, if there’s a way to remove JS from this specific problem, I would recommend [Feature Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@supports).

```
@supports (display: var(--prop)) {
  h1 { font-weight: normal; }
  /* all the css, even without var() */
}
```

Feature queries test support for syntax. You don’t have to query for `display`; you could use any property you want. Likewise, the value of `--prop` need not even exist. All you’re doing is checking to see if the browser knows how to read that syntax.

(I just chose `display` because almost every browser supports it. If you use `flex-wrap` or something, you won’t catch the browsers that do support custom props but that don’t support flexbox.)

*Sidenote:* I prefer calling them **Custom Properties** because that is exactly what they are: properties defined by the author. Yes, you can *use* them as variables, but there are certain advantages to them as properties, such as DOM inheritance:

```
body    { --color-heading: green; }
article { --color-heading: blue; }
h1      { color: var(--color-heading); } /* no need for descendant selectors */
```

Comment: Why you don't have to use JS detection, the question was for javascript, and it should be assumed there are situations where such detections are absolutely a must to do in JS, and not in CSS. For example, you want to prevent a script from running or even being imported, if no support for its usage is available.

Comment: Or to use feature detection to determine whether the current browser meets your minimum requirements 

Answer (score 1):

I had problems getting the `window.CSS.supports` method to work for testing css variables in chrome 49 (even though it has native support). Ended up doing this:

```
var supportsCssVars = function() {
    var s = document.createElement('style'),
        support;

    s.innerHTML = ":root { --tmp-var: bold; }";
    document.head.appendChild(s);
    support = !!(window.CSS && window.CSS.supports && window.CSS.supports('font-weight', 'var(--tmp-var)'));
    s.parentNode.removeChild(s);
    return support;
}

console.log("Supports css variables:", supportsCssVars());
```

Seems to work in all browsers I tested.
Probably the code can be optimised though.